# Why is a Vitali set non-measurable even though it is a member of the power set of $[0,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

By definition, the sets in a $\sigma$-algebra are called *measurable*; so, consider the power set of $[0,1]$. This is a $\sigma$-algebra, so the sets in this collection should be measurable. But a Vitali set is a subset of $[0,1]$, so it should then be called measurable as well.

Why then do we say that a Vitali set is non-measurable, even though it is a member of the power set of $[0,1]$?

Comment: I'm not specialist of the subject, but I recall it has to do with breaking the invariance by translation of the measure.

Comment: For a $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma,$ a set being $\Sigma$-measurable just means it is a member of $\Sigma.$ However when we just say a set of real numbers is measurable, we mean with respect to a specific $\sigma$-algebra, namely the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra. The Vitali set, like every subset of $[0,1]$, is $\mathcal P([0,1])$-measurable, however it is not Lebesgue measurable. We don’t care much about $\mathcal P([0,1])$ as a $\sigma$-algebra because there are not many interesting measures on it. On the other hand the Lebesgue measure on the Lebesgue algebra is usually what we’re interested in.

Comment: The construction of the Vitali set shows it cannot be a member of any sigma algebra that has a nontrivial translation-invariant measure. If our aim to extend the idea of interval length to more obscure subsets of the reals, this tells we cannot extend it to *all* subsets of the reals.

Answer (score 2):

A [measurable space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurable_space) is a pair $(X,\mathcal A)$ where $X$ is a set and $\mathcal A\subseteq\wp(X)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. In that context a subset of $X$ is measurable iff it is an element of $\mathcal A$.

Looking at the Vitali set $V$ as a subset of $[0,1]$ it is a measurable subset wrt measurable space $([0,1],\mathcal A)$ iff $V\in\mathcal A$ .

So actually  not measures "decide" whether $V$ is a measurable set or is not.

You can start with $([0,1],\mathcal A)$ where $V\in\mathcal A$ (making $V$ measurable in advance) and then go looking for measures on that measurable space.

Examples are:

- $\mathcal A=\wp([0,1])$ and $\mu$ is the counting measure.
- $\mathcal A=\wp([0,1])$ and $\mu$ is the zero measure (your suggestion).
- $\mathcal A=\{\varnothing,V,V^{\complement},[0,1]\}$ and $\mu$ is the measure determined by e.g. $\mu(V)=4$ and $\mu(V^{\complement})=\pi$.

For completeness let me mention that a triple $(X,\mathcal A,\mu)$ where $(X,\mathcal A)$  is a measurable space and $\mu$ is a measure on it (i.e. a function $\mathcal A\mapsto[0,\infty]$ that has certain properties) is a [measure space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_space).

---

On the other hand you can start with a set $X$ and some function on its subsets that "has the looks" of a measure and then go for finding a $\sigma$-algebra such that the function restricted to it is indeed a measure.